# Again but without solution: error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I write a program with my class:

```
class COrder
{
public:
    COrder();
    ~COrder();


public:
        ...
    CList < CItem > m_oItem;
        ...
};
```

which suppose to have list od object of my other class:

```
class CItem
{
public:
    CItem();
    ~CItem();

public:
    int m_i;
    double m_d;
    CString m_o;
};
```

and compiler give me error like this in title. Any ideas why ? 
In program I use COrder in map:

```
CMap <CString, LPCTSTR, COrder, COrder> m_map
```

Quote:

> Add copy-constructor and assignment operator to your class COrder.

I add operator= to my class:

```
COrder& operator=( const COrder oNewOrder )
{
        ...
    m_oItem.AddTail( oNewOrder.m_oItem.GetTail() );
        ...
    return *this;
}
```

but what you mean by adding "copy-constructor" ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccb3dh5c.aspx i found this but how to implement it in my code. i can't change CList class.

Comment: You should reconsider your information-hiding as you have none...

Comment: It's not my priority now, but ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13458/CMap-How-to

Add copy-constructor and assignment operator to your class `COrder`. This makes the class copyable.

[*If class is used in as Key then you need HashKey() and CompareElemenst() in that class*]

Also note that [STL containers are superior to MFC containers](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?504249-How-to-declare-CMap-for-two-CLists&p=1976284#post1976284).

You get an error because CMap has default copy-ctor but `CMap` and `CList` is derived from `CObject` and `CObject` declares private copy constructor and operator=.

So, `CMap` doesn't offer a copy semantic "out of the box".

I would suggest you to use STL `std::map` container, which is designed in a 
way to implement copy semantic out-of-the-box.

What you don't have with STL out of the box is serialization only.

Note that `std::map` does not have the confusing `ARG_KEY` and `ARG_VALUE` 
templates.
`std::map` just has the Key and Type template arguments (in its basic form).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s44w4h2s%28VS.80%29.aspx

Or else you can go by the pointer way as Ajay suggested by which you will just shut up the compiler.

Comment: Ty very much, can u answer my question above?

Comment: Yes, you can't change CList class. But atleast you can derive one and make your own class derived from CList and then you can use the trick by adding those copy constructor and assignment overload to your class.

Comment: Ok, I thought the same afterwards. So in my copy-constructor i should copy all elements of my list to my copied list (in a loop) ?

Comment: Yes you will have to add code to copy the list by iterating the source list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement:

`CList<CItem> m_oItem;`

And the trigger statement (or some usage):

`CMap <CString, LPCTSTR, COrder, COrder> m_map;`

Why? Well, `CMap` would call copy constructor and/or assignment operator for `COrder`. You didn't provide any, but compiler provides them from your class (i.e. for `COrder`). This class contains a `CList` object, which is inherited from `CObject`. `CObject` doesn't provide (or better say: **Prevents**) copy-constructor or assignment operator.

As a result, the compiler raises the error. Unfortunately, the (bad) compiler doesn't give you back-trace of this error.

Best bets for as the solution:

- `CList < CItem* > m_oItem;`
- `CList<CItem> *m_poItem;`
- Use or implement your own collection.